# Congratulations to DucatiKiller for reaching 10,000 Points!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

Everyone please congratulate DucatiKiller for reaching the 10k threshold! Good job brother! :D Your presence here has made a tremendous difference!

Comment: Good job, keep revvin

Comment: thanks @Anarach  I suggest we start an MC chat room.  What do you think?

Comment: Yay - that's 8 of us over 10k now! Congratulations!

Comment: @RoryAlsop  Wow.  I didn't realize.  That's pretty cool.   :-)